# Dynamic advanced search library?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, search

I'm getting ready to cook up an MVC search page that will allow the user to build their own query.  They might search for something by title, then add an "AND" criteria of objects posted before a certain date, "OR" objects with a certain tag.  Before I plow into the code, is there a library or something that already gives functionality like this?

Comment: where will the data be stored? in a database? in a file? in memory?

Comment: An EF database, model-first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here have a look at [dynamic predicate builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Comment: I guess I'm looking for more of a Views library, but this will likely prove useful on the controller side. Thank you.